# Expected `onChange` listener to be a function, instead got a value of `object` type

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react and practicing on react.On building my react app on handling event onChange I am always getting the error Error: Expected `onChange` listener to be a function, instead got a value of `object` type.

I have also tried to do this
onChange={()=> searchChange}
and it still not printing the event.

Search box Component

```
import React from 'react';

const SearchBox=(searchfield,searchChange)=>{
    return (
        <div className='pa2'>
        <input
        className='pa3 ba b--green bg-lightest-blue' 
        type='search' 
        placeholder='search robots'
        onChange={searchChange}
        />
        </div>
        );
}
export default SearchBox;
```

App Component

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import Cardlist from './Cardlist';
import {robots} from './robots';
import SearchBox from './SearchBox';

class App extends Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state={
            robots:robots,
            searchfield:''
        }
    }
    onSearchChange=(event)=> {
        console.log(event);
    }
    render(){
        return(
        <div className='tc'>
        <h1> RoboFriends </h1>
        <SearchBox searchChange={this.onSearchChange}/>
        <Cardlist robots={this.state.robots} />
        </div>
        );
    }
}
export default App;
```

I want to print the event on the console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing a prop `searchChange` from `App` to `SearchBox` component -

`<SearchBox searchChange={this.onSearchChange}/>`

But you're using it wrong here -

```js
const SearchBox=(searchfield,searchChange)=>{
```

Change the de-structured props of `SearchBox` to -

```js
const SearchBox=({ searchfield,searchChange })=>{
```